# Connecting chrome native messages to a existing instance on windows

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have a created a chrome background script and a host using python run by executing a bat file which is linked in the "manifest". Everything kinda works but as far as I understand every time I connect to host with my chrome extension for native messaging I create the python instance and execute the code.

But is it possible to connect to a existing instance(for example I execute a python script) and view the output? I hope my question is understandable.

I also do not understand why when I execute a bat file e get a cmd window but when my chrome background app connect to chrome and data is sent between there is no window. Why this might be like that?

Comment: Not fully clear though. Do you want to make Chrome run only one instance (which can be achieved by carefully reusing the port) or connect with another program to a running python script (which is a very broad topic and not connected to [tag:chrome-native-messaging])?

Comment: The scenario that i want is  to: 1. execute a bat file manually which is linked in the manifest file and when chrome is open for it to connect to the existing host!

Comment: I believe the only solution then would be to have Chrome call a "proxy" that in turn connects to a host, ensuring only one instance of the host is running.. Chrome will never reuse an existing process upon connect, not with the currently available type `stdio`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Xan! Maybe you could answer the second question.