# How can I send a message from Desktop application to Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I want to send a message from my python app to google chrome extension which will activate the extension. I am able to call my python app from my extension but in that case extension opens the new instance of python app every time but I want my extension to make connection with active instance of the app else extension should wait for the app to be active to connect.

Kindly refer these two questions to understand the problem -

[[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108698/connecting-chrome-native-messages-to-a-existing-instance-on-windows]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108698/connecting-chrome-native-messages-to-a-existing-instance-on-windows)

[how to use NativeMessaging to connect to a native application(.exe) ,but don't launch the .exe,just send the message background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155633/how-to-use-nativemessaging-to-connect-to-a-native-application-exe-but-dont-l)

Comment: There's no API except nativeMessaging for this task and it works only as described in the documentation. You can write a separate utility that will relay the message from extension to a running python app. Or your python app can listen on an http port so the extension may connect directly via XMLHttpRequest/fetch.

Comment: I would love to do this task with native messaging, but when i make a connection using browser.runtime.connectNative(), a new instance of the python app is created, but I want my extension to wait for the user to open the python app or connect with existing instance and I am unable to find a solution for that. Is there any other solution for this problem other then XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: An extension can't listen for external messages without launching the app instance. So either you need to split the logic between native host and "main app" somehow, or you need to resort to polling a known localhost port from the extension that your app opens to see if it's active.

Comment: "a new instance of the python app is created" - my suggestion was to write an additional connector app that relays messages from your extension to your main python app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solutions @wOxxOm and Xan.